# Не могу закруглить края у кастомного (нарисованого) прогресс бара

Tags: android

Вобщем сделал я кастомный прогресс. Нашел Пример в нете, переделал его, в итоге получилось. Но есть проблема. прогресс вот такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно в верхнем квадратике, он закругленный. Но как видно на нижних двух, края ровные. Вот я и хочу их сделать точно такими же закруглеными. Кто поможет буду очень счастлив и боагодарен. Вот мой код который рисует все это сейчас

```
public class SemiCircleProgressBarView extends View {

    private Path mClippingPath;
    private float mPivotX;
    private float mPivotY;
    private Context context;

    private float progress = 0.0f;
    private float thickness;

    public SemiCircleProgressBarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        initializeImage();
    }

    public SemiCircleProgressBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        initializeImage();
    }

    private void initializeImage() {
        mClippingPath = new Path();
        mPivotX = 0;
        mPivotY = 0;
    }

    public void setClipping(float progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        mClippingPath.reset();
        thickness = 0.25f * getHeight();
        mClippingPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
        mClippingPath.addCircle(0.5f * getWidth(), getHeight(), getHeight() - thickness, Path.Direction.CCW);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float angle = (progress * 180) / 100;

        RectF oval = new RectF(mPivotX, mPivotY, mPivotX + getWidth(), mPivotY + 2.0f * getHeight());

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.progress));

        Paint pbg = new Paint();
        pbg.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.progress_bg));

//        Paint cr = new Paint();
//        cr.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.clipPath(mClippingPath);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 180, 360, true, pbg);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 180, angle, true, p);
//        canvas.drawCircle(0.5f * thickness,getHeight(),30,cr);

        double radAngle = Math.toRadians(angle);
        float px = getWidth () - (float)Math.cos(radAngle) * ((float)getWidth() -  thickness);
        float py = getHeight() - (float)Math.sin(radAngle) * ((float)getHeight() - 0.5f * thickness);

        canvas.drawCircle(0.5f * px, py, 0.5f * thickness, p);
    }
}
```

мне нужно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обновление**
Установите объекту Paint круглую кисть перед рисованием дуги

```
setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)
```

Comment: вот честно ниче не понял. Может пару строк кода?

Comment: ну я сделал так. и? просто рисуется не сначала. а дальше то что. как закруглить?

Comment: вы не поняли меня. У меня по краям нет откружности. мне нужно чтобы слева и справа сама дуга была с закруглеными краями

Comment: сбил Ваш рисунок с толку. там в центре кисть круглая. а по коду - квадратная
попробуйте этот код:
`Paint p1 = new Paint();
            p1.setStrokeWidth(30f);
            p1.setColor(Color.RED);
            p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            p1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

            RectF rectf = new RectF(100,100,300,250);
            canvas.drawArc(rectf, 180, 160, false, p1);`
основное тут - `setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);`

Comment: к сожалению ничего это не дало. а что должно получиться вообще? мне не нужена круглая кисть. мне края самой дуги нижнии нужны круглые

Comment: вот как раз, если в onDraw исполнить тот код, что я написал, получишь [дугу с закругленными концами](http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1506/0a/e02f8e16d5d0.png)

Comment: ваш совет был неприменим к коду который я привел. но он натолкнул меня на идею, и я ее реализовал. спасибо!